# Quantile regression for 2nd order polynomial using StatsModels

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I have followed the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185046/using-statsmodels-to-plot-quantile-regression-for-2nd-order-polynomial) by PJW for plotting a 2nd order polynomial quantile regression. The OLS model seems to be a good fit for my data but the quantile lines came out really wacky and I haven't been able to figure out where the code has gone wrong. I have attached my code below and the chart with only OLS regression line and the chart with the funky quantiles. Any help would be appreciated!

Scatter graph with 2nd order polynomial, regression line in red:
[image]

Same scatter graph with an OLS 2nd order polynomial regression line (black) and quantile lines (0.05, 0.5, 0.95) that are clearly wrong (red dotted):
[image]

```
def plot_poly_centiles(parameter_df):
# function to plot quantile lines using polynomial regression

    par_name = parameter_df.columns[1]

    # plot a scatter graph of the data
    plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    sns.scatterplot(x='age', y=par_name, data=parameter_df, marker='.', color='blue', alpha=0.1)

    model = smf.quantreg(f'{par_name} ~ age + np.power(age, 2)', parameter_df)
    result = model.fit(q=0.5)
    print(result.summary())

    # Quantile regression for 5 quantiles
    quantiles = [.05, .25, .50, .75, .95]

    # get all model result instances in a list
    result_all = [model.fit(q=q) for q in quantiles]

    result_ols = smf.ols(f'{par_name} ~ age + np.power(age, 2)', parameter_df).fit()

    # create x for prediction
    x = np.arange(parameter_df.age.min(), parameter_df.age.max(), 50)
    predicted_df = pd.DataFrame({'age': x})

    # plot quantile lines
    for qm, result in zip(quantiles, result_all):
        # get prediction for the model and plot
        # here we use a dict which works the same way as the df in ols
        y_cent = result.predict({'age': x})
        plt.plot(x, y_cent, linestyle='--', linewidth=1, color='red')

    # plot ols line
    y_ols_predicted = result_ols.predict(predicted_df)
    plt.plot(x, y_ols_predicted, color='k', linewidth=1, label='OLS')

    plt.xlabel('age in days')
    plt.ylabel(f'{par_name}')
    plt.title(f'Polynomial regression centiles of {par_name} in children')
    plt.show()

    return parameter_df
```

Comment: I think you need a constant in your quantile regression, so `~ 1 + age + ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I have had a few suggestions to add a constant. I've tried your suggestion by adding `model = smf.quantreg(f'{par_name} ~ 1 + age + np.power(age, 2)', parameter_df)`, and I have tried adding a constant to the dataframe using `sm.add_constant(df)` but neither made any difference to the quantile plots - Note I am a relative beginner to Python and have even less knowledge of statistics!

Comment: possibly a scaling problem: power polynomials get badly scaled if the x values are large. Try with rescaled age, e.g. divide age by 1000.